# C - Default value for pointer within a struct

Tags: c, pointers

I have the following very simplistic implementation for a single linked list in C:

```
typedef struct Node{
        int data;
    struct Node *next;  
} node;


void printLL(node * start);
void addNode(node * head, node * add);

int main()
{
    node first;
    first.data = 99;
    first.next = NULL;

    node second;
    second.data = 11;

    addNode(&first, &second);   
    printLL(&first);    
}

void addNode(node * head, node * add)
{
    if(head->next)
    {
        addNode(head->next, add);
    }
    else 
    {
        head->next = add;
    }
}

void printLL(node * start)
{
    printf("Data is %d\n", start->data);
    if (start->next) {
        printLL(start->next);
    }
}
```

What I'm confused about is that if I don't explicitly set first.next = NULL, I get a EXE_BAD_ACCESS error.  It happens when I try and check if that property is set or not to determine if the call should be made recursively.  The other thing I don't understand is that if I set first.next to point to 'second', all functions work even though for 'second' I don't explicitly set it's next to NULL.  So it seems as though there is some inconsistency in the default value for a pointer defined within a struct.  Of course I'm probably doing something totally wrong but would be grateful if somebody could shed light on the matter.  To boil everything down my questions are:

1. What is the default value for a pointer defined within a struct?
2. Assuming that there is no default, is there a simple way to set a default within the structs definition? (I looked through some C books and couldn't find an answer to this question)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> So it seems as though there is some inconsistancy in the default value for a pointer defined within a struct.

That's exactly the problem - the compiler is does not set an automatic (local) variable to any default.  So you may get something that results in `EXE_BAD_ACCESS`, or you may get something that appears to work.  It's luck of the draw (and is a bug even if it appears to work).

One of the drawbacks to C is that you are responsible for ensuring that your variables are initialized properly.  A compiler may assist with warnings, not all compilers are as good as others in that regard.

> is there a simple way to set a default within the structs definition?

There is not a way to do this in the definition of a struct. However, you can initialize a struct when a variable of that type is declared:

```
node first = { 99, NULL };
```

Comment: What if I call some library that gives me back a struct like node and the author was lazy and forgot to set a default value for the pointer.  Then I come along and try to check if something is there but it blows up, any other way to safetly check if that pointer has been initalized?

Comment: you are right, but for one thing. There is default initialization for all fields that are not mentioned explicitly. And together with designated initializers this can become much simpler to handle that you seem to indicate. Please see my answer.

Comment: @user398746: Short answer no, longer answer, get a better lib. If you passed data to the lib, initialise before the call (good habit regardless of what the docs say anyway). If the lib is not initialising data or allocates, your toast.....

Answer (score 1):

There's no default value for any pointer, it contains a garbage value. Unless you initialize all pointers with your own default value.

Answer (score 0):

<del>Default values might depent on C compiler so it mostly better to provide them.</del>

You have to init it after you created your struct instance like `second.next = NULL`.

Comment: No default values don't depend on the compiler. The C standard prescribes exactly how variables are to be initialized.

Comment: Several other answer say there is no default and I kind of recall that there are C compiler which will kind of set thing to 0 but several dont. But maybe I mix this up with another language, I am not sure anymore.

Answer (score 0):

There is no default value for anything within a struct (unless it is created statically). And there is no way of providing one - if you want that, you should use C++, which provides constructors to  do exactly that. If sticking with C, you need to initialise the struct explicitly.

Comment: Sure there are. please see my answer.

Comment: @Jens Your answer seems to be about explicit initialisation.

Comment: you say "there is no default value for anything within a struct" which is just wrong. The default value is `0` if it is initialized implicitly, either by being static, or by having an initiliazer that omits that field.

Answer (score 0):

On call to `addNode(&first, &second);`, in the `if` condition, you are doing `head->next` which is what causing the problems. `next` is not initialized **by default** and is causing EXE_BAD_ACCESS at run time.

But when you set it to **NULL**, the condition in `if` statement fails and is getting you to the `else` statement where you are actually assigning the pointer.

Comment: Is there a 'safer' check then to see if it is or isn't initalized?  Seems like the best bet is to initalize all values in the struct but let's assume I get a struct from some other call I didn't write, how could I program defensively?  I suppose not since it could look like a valid address to a node or may not be.

Comment: AFAIK, it is difficult to know. Because, an uninitialized pointer has undefined behavior. It might some times point to valid locations and work as if nothing went wrong. So, the best way is to set it to `null`. Also check the @Michael Burr solution which is what you need to do.

Answer (score 0):

If you want default pointer values, you can create a factory method that returns a new instance of the struct with the values set to your desired default values.

Answer (score 0):

There is no default value. Each memory location will hold on to whatever value it has unless explicitly modified. Though this behavior itself is compiler dependent. The bottom line, you cant assume that it will contain a particular value.

To set a default value, a good practice is to explicitly assign values to the `struct` attributes whenever you create an instance of it.

If you were using `C++`, you would have constructors where you would/should set default values of the  members.

Answer (score 0):

Automatic variables are not initialized at all in C, regardless whether they are `struct` or not. You have to initialize them yourself.

But in contrast to what most answer here seem to imply **there is a default** for initialization of any data type, including pointers. This is done as if any component would be explicitly initialized by a plain value '0'. For your example

```
node first = { .data = 99 };
```

would have done the trick. `next` is then guaranteed to be initialized properly. (If you don't have C99 omit the `.data =` and hope that you never change the layout of your `struct` :)

Observe also that this might be different from zeroing out a `struct` with `memset` or so. On some architectures the all 0 bit pattern might not be the correct initialization for a null pointer or a `double`. So better stick to what the language itself provides as initialization mechanism.